# How to create a linked list that generates random numbers until it generates a specific number

Tags: c, loops, linked-list, iteration, random-seed

Im prompted to create a linked list that generates numbers 0-50. When the list generates 49, instead of printing 49 its supposed prints out the list. My issue is trying to figure out how to make the loop so it can actually perform this tasl.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printList();
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

int main() {
    srand(time(0)); //srand sets starting value for series of random ints
    
    int x = rand()%50 + 1; //gets random number in range 1-50, including 50
    
    struct Node* head = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
   
    head->data = x; //assigns head to the random value between 0 and 50
    head->next = NULL;
    
    printList(head); //calls funtion to print list
    
    return 0;
}

void printList (struct Node* n){
    while (n != NULL){
        printf(" %d ", n->data);
        n = n->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"how to make the loop*" `for (i=0; i < 50; i++)`? Please clarify what specific part of "make the loop" do you have difficulty with?

Comment: @kaylum i wasn't sure what the condition was going to be for the loop, because i was assuming the list would go on as long as it needed to until the number 49 was generated.

Comment: I see. Sorry, I misunderstood your question as meaning "until 49 numbers are generated". I see an answer has been posted and it looks good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int rnd;
while((rnd = rand() % 50) != 49)
{ 
    add_tolist(rnd);
}

printlist();
```

Comment: in my code i have x=rand() % 50, so i would replace rnd with x and still be fine?

Comment: also, this would just require me to make an add_tolist function outside of main right? apologies if my questions seem dumb i just really want to clarify